# update multiples rows with event scheduler

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

i have condition like this, i have history of payment and if the status still waiting for payment in 1 day, the stock will back to first values according to the number of products purchased.
and i have query like this

```
> CREATE EVENT `stok_sch` ON SCHEDULE
>     EVERY 1 SECOND
>     DO BEGIN
>     UPDATE product a
>     SET a.stock = a.stock +
>     (select ifnull((select sum(amount) from order_detail x left join order y using (idOrder) 
>     where y.status='Waiting for payment' and x.idProduct=a.idProduct 
>     and (date_format(y.order_date,'%Y%m%d')+1 = date_format(now(),'%Y%m%d')+0 or date_format
>     (y.order_date,'%Y%m%d')+1 < date_format(now(),'%Y%m%d')+0) group by x.idProduct),0));
>     
>     UPDATE order set status ='Cancel' where status ='Waiting for payment' and (date_format(order_date,'%Y%m%d')+1 < date_format
>     
>     (now(),'%Y%m%d')+0 OR date_format(order_date,'%Y%m%d')+1 = date_format(now(),'%Y%m%d')+0);
>     END$$;
```

i have updated my query and it works fine if i run it  without event schedule, but when i combine it with event scheduler the stock of product updated double from amount of purchased.
any ideas to fix this?

Comment: Please, give format to the query :)

Comment: hi thanks for the help :D this my first time

Comment: @yobuD - select code, press ctrl+k == formatting for you.

Answer (score 0):

Two things you can try:

1) Replace `LEFT JOIN` by `JOIN` so you get only acual orders.

2) Dont reference to ab.amount inside your Subquery in `SET stock = stock + ( ...)` part. Reference to x.amount instead:

The query will look like this now:

```
UPDATE product AS a, product_detail AS ab, order AS b
    SET stock=a.stock + 
        (select sum(x.amount) as amount 
            from product_detail x 
            join order y  using (idOrder) 
            where y.status='waiting for payment' 
            and x.idProduct = a.idProduct 
            group by x.idProduct
        ) 
     WHERE a.idProduct=ab.idProduct 
     AND ab.idOrder=b.idOrder 
     AND b.status='waiting for payment' 
     and (date_format(order_date,'%Y%m%d')+1 = date_format(now(),'%Y%m%d')+0 or date_format(order_date,'%Y%m%d')+1 < date_format(now(),'%Y%m%d')+0)
;
```

Comment: well it was work fine when i run it without event schedule, but i've got another problem, When i combine the query with my event scheduler, the stock update twice from amount of purchased.
example: table product with idproduct ss1 stock 4, then I ordered the product ss1 as much as 2  and my status 'Waiting for payment'. and i update my date from pc and and my status changed into cancel which is true and the stock should be 4 like the first, but the problem it was updated doubled and become 6..
why is that? @Benni

Answer (score 0):

Use date comparisons instead of transforming to numbers, also realize that if someone places an order at 10pm, this order will be cancelled at right after midnight.

```
UPDATE product p
JOIN (SELECT
        d.idProduct,
        SUM(d.amount) amount
      FROM
          `order` o
      JOIN product_detail d
        ON o.order_id = d.order_id
      WHERE
         o.status = 'waiting for payment'
         AND
         DATE(o.order_date) >=  CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY
      GROUP BY idProduct
     ) pd
     ON p.idProduct = pd.idProduct
SET
    p.stock = p.stock + pd.amount
WHERE
    p.idProduct = pd.idProduct
```

Comment: hey thanks for the answer, but it was work the same i still got problem with the stock..it was update twice when i combine the query with my event shceduler? any ideas? @Gervs

Comment: Oops, my mistake, forgot group by in subquery. Changed my answer

Comment: why when i started the event with this query? the stock updated twice/double from amount of purchased?